# how to return to swing frame after clicking ok button of confirm dialog

Tags: java, swing

Select a checkbox and check if text field related to it is filled with input

```
 chckbxDictionary = new JCheckBox();
 txtDictionaryStartPage = new JTextField();    
 JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
 btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if(chckbxDictionary.isSelected()){
            if(txtDictionaryStartPage.getText().equals("")){
                    int type=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "enter start page", "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if(type==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                        //if ok return to frame and focus txtDictionaryStartPage for user input
                    }
                }
       }
  }
}
```

After clicking ok button on confirm dialog, I want to go back to jframe and focus the required text field for user to enter input and wait till input is entered.

Comment: Are the chckbxDictionary and that JFrame in same file (same class)?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are in the same class, according to the [`JavaDoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#grabFocus()):

> public boolean requestFocusInWindow()
>
> Requests that this Component
>   gets the input focus. Refer to Component.requestFocusInWindow() for a
>   complete description of this method. If you would like more
>   information on focus, see How to Use the Focus Subsystem, a section in
>   The Java Tutorial.

So in your case, you could do:

```
if(type==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    txtDictionaryStartPage.requestFocusOnWindow();
}
```

Comment: text field is not in focus and i am not able to return to frame to accept input on clicking ok button

Answer (score 0):

If they are in same class, you can do:

```
 chckbxDictionary = new JCheckBox();
 txtDictionaryStartPage = new JTextField();    
 JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
 btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if(chckbxDictionary.isSelected()){
            if(txtDictionaryStartPage.getText().equals("")){
                    int type=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "enter start page", "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if(type==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                        txtDictionaryStartPage.requestFocusInWindow();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
       }
  }
}
```

I am not sure that the part `frame.setVisible(true);` is required, but try. If you put that in your code, it doesn't hurt anyway.

Comment: When I think, I'm pretty sure that you need frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: Presumably the button (the event source for the actionPerformed callback ) is in the frame, so the frame has to be visible for the user to have clicked the button. So it is  superfluous to call frame.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 0):

first argument to `showConfirmDialog` should be changed from `null`, to `btnSubmit`

```
int type=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(btnSubmit, "enter start page", "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if(type==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
      txtDictionaryStartPage.requestFocusOnWindow();
}
```